# Selecting elements from list of lists that satisfy a condition

Tags: python, list, filter

I have the following list

```
a = [['a', 'b', 1], ['c', 'b', 3], ['c','a', 4], ['a', 'd', 2]]
```

and I'm trying to remove all the elements from the list where the last element is less than 3. So the output should look like

```
a = [['c', 'b', 3], ['c','a', 4]]
```

I tried to use filter in the following way

```
list(filter(lambda x: x == [_, _, 2], a))
```

Here _ tries to denote that the element in those places can be anything. I'm used to this kind of syntax from mathematica but I have been unable to find something like this in Python (is there even such a symbol in python ?).

I would prefer solution using map and filter as those are most intuitive for me.

Comment: `list(filter(lambda x: x[-1] > 2, a))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `x[-1] >= 3` in `lambda` to retain all sub lists with last value greater than or equal to `3`:

```
>>> a = [['a', 'b', 1], ['c', 'b', 3], ['c','a', 4], ['a', 'd', 2]]
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x[-1] >= 3, a))
[['c', 'b', 3], ['c', 'a', 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks, so simple. Any easy way now to drop the last element? i.e. to get from [['c', 'b', 3], ['c', 'a', 4]] to [['c', 'b'], ['c', 'a']]?

Comment: `for i in lst: del i[-1]` should do.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension approach:

```
a_new = [sublist for sublist in a if sublist[-1] >= 3]
```

Comment: You need to change that `<` to a `>=`

Comment: OP says *"..last element"* so it would be safer to go with `sublist[-1]`.

Comment: `<` should be `>=`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [['a', 'b', 1], ['c', 'b', 3], ['c','a', 4], ['a', 'd', 2]]
```

Filter above list with list comprehension like:

```
b = [x for x in a if x[-1] >= 3]
```

Comment: Please dont just code drop. Explain what you have done and why. there are many different approaches here, why should we pick this one instead of another?